# Non-pejorative synonym of "notoriety"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, synonyms

I'm trying to say:

> He probably gained some __________ [good notoriety] from this picture.

I was thinking [publicity](https://www.wordnik.com/words/publicity), but that connotes some kind of negative to me as well (like the stuff you see in gossip magazines at the checkout line).

I want a word as powerfully positive as [notoriety](https://www.wordnik.com/words/notoriety) is powerfully negative.

Comment: How about *recognition*?

Comment: consider "fame"

Comment: 'publicity' is fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Public] acclaim** is the term I'd use.

> acclaim ... noun
>
> Enthusiastic and public praise.
>
> ‘she has won acclaim for her commitment to democracy’

[[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/acclaim)]

From [Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/acclaim):

> • Lamboume's work is not widely known today, yet during the 1950s he
>   received great critical acclaim.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the word **[prestige](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prestige)**.

> 1 :  standing or estimation in the eyes of people :  weight or credit in general opinion
>
> 2 :  commanding position in people's minds

This word carries a very positive connotation, just as "notoriety" does a negative one.

> He probably gained some **prestige** from this picture.

If you wanted a word that is non-pejorative and possibly has less of a positive connotation, but implies fame as "notoriety" does, you could use **[repute](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/repute)**.

> the state of being favorably known, spoken of, or esteemed

In the context of your sentence, it's more likely that you would say **reputation**.

Answer (score 3):

**Notability** is a possibility, though it is more neutral than positive:

> **2. a.** Noteworthiness, distinction, prominence; an instance of this.
>
> "The village of Kexby has always enjoyed a notability out of all relation to its size."

(OED)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ***​[visibility](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/visibility)***:

> the degree to which something is seen by the public:
>
> - The increasing visibility of the city's poor and homeless has forced the council into taking action.

(Camvridge Dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

One such word is ***popularity***.

> He probably gained some ***popularity*** from this picture.

ODO:

> **[popularity](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/popularity)**
>
> *NOUN*
>
> The state or condition of being liked, admired, or supported by many
>   people.
>
> ‘Jordan's popularity is growing and she moves swiftly on to Dane
>   Bowers, the pop star.’

Answer (score 0):

I think I was getting after the idea of **reputation**.

The group in focus within which he gained the "positive notoriety" is a kind of guild or academy (formal or informal) of professional photographers.

So maybe my sentence could have gone:

> He probably gained a reputation for that photo.

By itself, the word might be ambiguous as to whether the reputation is positive or negative, but in the context of the original facebook post, it would have been clearly positive.  Plus, I like the mystique lended by the ambiguity.

It should be noted that this is funny because the word reputation was all around me on this site...

Comment: 'A reputation' is almost always considered negative, that is, it is assumed to be 'a bad reputation'. "He got a reputation for not returning emails"

Answer (score 0):

Acclimation or resonance? Reconsiliation.

Comment: This would benefit from definitions or sources justifying how these words address the question.  Please take a moment to see the [help].